# Compare local data with current date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I have this date format returned from api which is local date

`"date":"2023-07-14"`

i want to compare this date with the current date

i was trying to compare like this

```
 if(new Date(this.date)==new Date())
```

but could not find the how to format both the date because both have different formats.

Comment: `Date`s are objects, so you cannot compare them using simple equality (an object is only equal to itself).

Comment: Local date, i.e., local time zone and not UTC?

Answer (score 2):

To parse a given date as local date, instead of an UTC date you'll have to provide a time, but no offset.

```
new Date("2023-07-14") // parses as UTC date
new Date("2023-07-14T00:00:00") // parses as local date
```

This behaviour is explained in the [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#using_date.parse) documentation, which is used by the Date constructor.

`new Date()` will give you a local date, that you can compare against the API date. Important is that both must be either local, or UTC (aka use the same timezone offset). Since `new Date()` (without arguments) will always return a local date, we parse the API date as local date as well by appending `"T00:00:00"`. With both dates using the same timezone offset, you can compare their [`toDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString) outputs.

```js
const apiDateString = "2023-07-14"; // local date

const apiDate = new Date(apiDateString + "T00:00:00"); // parse as local date
const currentDate = new Date(); // now as local date

if (apiDate.toDateString() === currentDate.toDateString()) {
  console.log("same");
} else {
  console.log("different");
}

// just to showcase the differences
const wrongDate = new Date(apiDateString);
console.log(`currentDate = ${currentDate}`);
console.log(`apiDate     = ${apiDate}`);
console.log(`wrongDate   = ${wrongDate}`);
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Foreword

JavaScript `Date`s are horrible; very horrible.

If you are just doing one little thing here and there, it's okay to work with them directly if you're careful. Otherwise, use something else. Until [`Temporal`](https://blogs.igalia.com/compilers/2020/06/23/dates-and-times-in-javascript/) lands and is widely supported, the alternatives are `Temporal` polyfills and date and time libraries ([Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/), [Day.js](https://day.js.org/en/), etc.).

#### Premise

Vocabulary, so we're on the same page:

- date: Something with year, month, and day information; no time.
- time: Something with time information; no date.

---

You have a string (from an API) holding a *local* date, in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`, with no attached timezone information.
You want to compare this to the current local date and see if they are equal.

#### Solutions

There are a number of approaches here. I'll cover two:

- Create a local date string and compare the date strings directly.
- Parse the API date as a local date and compare the `Date`s.

##### Create a local date string

As the API date is in `YYYY-MM-DD` format, we can get the current local date in the same format and compare them directly.

Unfortunately, the only way to reliably get the current *local* date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format is to manually construct it. This can be done as follows:

```js
function getCurrentLocalDate() {
  const now = new Date()
  return now.getFullYear() +
    "-" +
    (now.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, "0") +
    "-" +
    now.getDate().toString().padStart(2, "0")
}
```

Then we can compare this to the API date.

```js
const apiDate = "2023-07-14"
const currentDate = getCurrentLocalDate()

console.log(apiDate, currentDate, apiDate === currentDate)

function getCurrentLocalDate() {
  const now = new Date()
  return now.getFullYear() +
    "-" +
    (now.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, "0") +
    "-" +
    now.getDate().toString().padStart(2, "0")
}
```

The above example is using a hardcoded date as the API date, so to examine it properly would require setting your system's date and time manually. I'm afraid I can't think of an in-code workaround other than reusing the `getCurrentLocalDate()` function, which obviously kind of breaks the integrity of this example. The other option is to paste it into your own browser console or similar and edit and run it yourself there.

##### Parse the API date

(I see [@3limin4t0r](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3982562/3limin4t0r) already [suggested this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76689655/15261914).)

This approach is to parse the API to a `Date` object and then compare that object to the current-date `Date` object.

This requires us to parse the API date as a local date. However, there is a historical quirk in the `Date` parsing mechanism which means that dates in the format we have are parsed as UTC:

> When the time zone offset is absent, **date-only forms are interpreted as a UTC time and date-time forms are interpreted as local time.** This is due to a historical spec error that was not consistent with ISO 8601 but could not be changed due to web compatibility. ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#:%7E:text=When%20the%20time%20zone%20offset%20is%20absent%2C%20date%2Donly%20forms%20are%20interpreted%20as%20a%20UTC%20time%20and%20date%2Dtime%20forms%20are%20interpreted%20as%20local%20time.))

Aside:
It is important to note that these "date-only forms" are specifically `YYYY`, `YYYY-MM`, and `YYYY-MM-DD`. As per those same docs, "implementations are allowed to support other date formats when the input fails to match [the [standard format](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-date-time-string-format)]." "Non-standard strings can be parsed in any way as desired by the implementation, including the time zone — most implementations use the local time zone by default."
Because of this, the API date has to be in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format for the exact approach below to work. If not, you would have to find a format which is—or can be made to be—reliably parsed as a local date in all target browsers.

The workaround is to add a dummy time to the date to make it be parsed as local:

```js
function localDateToDateObject(dateString) {
  return new Date(dateString + "T00:00:00")
}
```

With that in place, we can then compare this to the current date.

One approach is to compare the date strings:

```js
const apiDate = "2023-07-14"

const currentDate = new Date()

const here = currentDate.toDateString()
const there = localDateToDateObject(apiDate).toDateString()
console.log(here, there, here === there)

function localDateToDateObject(dateString) {
  return new Date(dateString + "T00:00:00")
}
```

Another is to compare the date parts manually:

```js
const apiDate = "2023-07-14"

const currentDate = new Date()

const here = currentDate
const there = localDateToDateObject(apiDate)
const areEqual =
  here.getFullYear() === there.getFullYear() &&
  here.getMonth() === there.getMonth() &&
  here.getDate() === there.getDate()

console.log(here, there, areEqual)

function localDateToDateObject(dateString) {
  return new Date(dateString + "T00:00:00")
}
```

If you also need to compare relative positions, you can set the current date's time to midnight and compare the timestamps:

```js
const apiDate = "2023-07-14"

const currentDate = new Date()
currentDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) // Set the time to midnight.

const here = currentDate.getTime()
const there = localDateToDateObject(apiDate).getTime()
console.log(here, there)

if (here > there)
  console.log("Now is later than then.")
else if (here < there)
  console.log("Now is earlier than then.")
else
  console.log("Now is the same as then.")

function localDateToDateObject(dateString) {
  return new Date(dateString + "T00:00:00")
}
```

The same caveats about the hardcoded API date apply to all of these.

Comment: The assertion "*date-only forms are interpreted as a UTC*" is only valid where the format is exactly yyyy-mm-dd. Any other date–only format (e.g. m/d/y) will **likely** be parsed as local, however the result is implementation dependent.

Comment: Thanks, @RobG. I've noted that.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing date strings is enough, but you should add your timezone offset.

Use `Date::setMinutes()` instead of timestamp arithmetic which is bad.

That would potentially allow to handle edge cases like Daylight Time Saving transitions.

```js
const d = new Date("2023-07-14"); // will be parsed to a UTC date
d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + d.getTimezoneOffset());
console.log(d.toString())

console.log('is today:', d.toDateString() === new Date().toDateString());
```

Comment: Um, it logs `false` for me?

Comment: @DarrylNoakes fixed, timezone should be added

Comment: As soon as time zone offsets are being manually handled, something is wrong... Use the ISO string utils and compare there.

Comment: there's no manual timezone offset

Comment: Right there: `but you should add your timezone offset:`

Comment: this timezone offset provided by JS so it's the same as converting to UTC string... matter of taste i would say

Comment: @DarrylNoakes the iso solution `(new Date()).toISOString().split('T')[0].toString()` doesn't work, commented it

Comment: I'm just wary of periodic timezone changes and leapseconds... Depends on the OP's use case, of course. I can't wait for Temporal to be widely supported.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes i thought JS timezone offset is dynamic because it's not a static Date's method. it's bound to a Date instance, so logically it should give different timezone offset for different dates

Comment: @DarrylNoakes i've improved it by avoid timestamp math which is BAD... so theoretically it should handle edge cases like DST changes

Comment: Instead of setting the minutes for the API date to counter it being parsed as UTC, you can append `"T00:00:00"` to it before passing it to `Date()`, and it will be parsed as a local date. See [@3limin4t0r's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76689655/15261914) or [my](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76689827/15261914) answer or more info.

Comment: DST is hardly an "edge case" since it applies to many places for about half the year. ;-) Manual parsing is likely a better solution than messing with timezone offset as it's a more obvious solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should first convert the date from the API into a Date object and then compare the parts of the date. Like as follows:

```
let apiDate = "2023-07-14";
let current = new Date();

// Convert API date to Date object
let apiDateObj = new Date(apiDate + "T00:00:00");

function checkDates(current, apiDateObj) {
  let tzOffset = apiDateObj.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
  let adjustedDateObj = new Date(apiDateObj.getTime() - tzOffset);

  if (adjustedDateObj.toDateString() === current.toDateString()) {
    return "Same date";
  } else {
    return "Different dates";
  }
}

console.log(checkDates(current, apiDateObj), "checkDates");
```

Answer (score -1):

To compare the date returned from the API with the current date both dates must have the same format.

Here is an example of code that does this:

```js
// Get the current date
let currentDate = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];

// Convert the API date 
let apiDate = new Date("2023-07-14").toISOString().split('T')[0];

// Compare the two dates
if (apiDate === currentDate) {
  console.log("The API date is equal to the current date.");
} else if (apiDate < currentDate) {
  console.log("The API date is before the current date.");
} else {
  console.log("The API date is after the current date.");
}
```

Comment: Your code includes the time in the calculations, while the question is only about the date.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes Thanks for noticing, I didn't notice so I fixed it

Comment: This parses the API date as a UTC, while it is actually local. Also, if the times and timezone offsets align, the ISO date strings will have different dates, as the offset can move the current local time into a different day.

Answer (score -1):

first you should but object in a variable then you should use(>, <, =, and >=) and don't use(==, !=, ===, or !==)

check this link for more info : https://sentry.io/answers/how-to-compare-two-dates-with-javascript/

```js
let date1 = new Date("2023-07-14")

let date2 = new Date("2023-07-14")


if(date1 = date2){
  console.log('yes')
}
```

Comment: You are using assignment instead of equality comparison in your `if`.

Comment: he convert date to right format by use new Date(this.date) but he use (==) to compare between two objects so he should use (=)

Comment: @AhmedEssam— `=` doesn't to comparison, it does assignment. Given *date1* and *date2* are objects, `if (date1 = date2)` will always be true whether they represent the dame date or not, and is more or less equivalent to `if (date2)`.

Answer (score -2):

You can get the current date as a string in `YYYY-MM-DD` format like this:

```js
const currentDate = (new Date()).toISOString().split('T')[0].toString();
console.log(currentDate);
```

Then simply compare with the API date.

Comment: new Date().toISOString() is enough

Comment: No, it is not. The full strong includes the time, while the question is only about the date part.

Comment: i mean you dont need to wrap new Date() in brackets

Comment: Oh, I see. It is more readable with them, though.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes doesn't work. you get an iso string and compare to local time, wrong. I have now 2023-07-14 00:30:00 and i got 2023-07-13

Comment: I didn't say the answer was correct. I only said that the parens made it more readable.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes wouldn't agree, moving  to "brackets hell" imho